# How do I store some background information associated with each item in a reyclerview in Android using Java?

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore

I am building a social networking app using Cloud Firestore. My Firestore collection posts contains the following fields: `title`, `text`, `uid`, `timestamp`, `latitude`, `longitude`, `photo url`.

Now when I fetch these posts and display them on a RecyclerView. I do not want the uid, latitude, longitude to be visible on the UI but they should be associated with the item for further use when the item is clicked.

What is the proper way to make the given association?

This is my POJO class:

```
public class Post {
    private String title;
    private String dp;
    private String description;
    private double latitutude,longitude;

    public String getUid() {
        return uid;
    }

    public void setUid(String uid) {
        this.uid = uid;
    }

    private String uid;
    public double getLatitutude() {
        return latitutude;
    }

    public void setLatitutude(double latitutude) {
        this.latitutude = latitutude;
    }

    public double getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(double longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    public String getDp() {
        return dp;
    }

    public void setDp(String dp) {
        this.dp = dp;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

This is the holder class:

```
public class PostHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ImageView dp;
    TextView title,desc;
    public PostHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        this.dp = itemView.findViewById(R.id.dpIV);
        this.title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.titleTV);
        this.desc = itemView.findViewById(R.id.descTV);
    }
}
```

And this is the adapter:

```
public class PostAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PostHolder> {

    Context c;
    ArrayList<Post> posts;

    public PostAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Post> posts) {
        this.c = c;
        this.posts = posts;

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public PostHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row,null);
        return new PostHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull PostHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.title.setText(posts.get(position).getTitle());
        holder.desc.setText(posts.get(position).getDescription());
        //loadBitmap(position,holder.dp);
        Glide.with(holder.dp.getContext())
                .load(posts.get(position).getDp())
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .apply(RequestOptions.circleCropTransform())
                .into(holder.dp);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        Log.e("AdapterSIZE",posts.size()+"");
        return posts.size();
    }

}
```

Comment: you need to structure your data in such a way that you only download enough to populate the UI , means load on demand

Comment: Yes, but I need the associated information as well. Do you mean I should query the database again when the user clicks on a particular list item?

Comment: yes you should query again , that is why you need to structure data such that so query will be fast , just download enough data , it will make the response time less and save you from huge billing cost , because if you download data which is probably never going to get consumed and if you get enough user then that downloading will reflect in the bill

Comment: I won't query again just for this few data, but I don't get what problem do you have. In your adapter you have the Post Arraylist, all this data should be there even if it's not shown in the RecyclerView and you can use it on click or whenever you need it.

Comment: make sure you don't learn the lesson hard way -> read this https://pamartinezandres.com/lessons-learnt-the-hard-way-using-firebase-realtime-database-c609b52b9afb

Comment: You say "I do not want the uid, latitude, longitude to be visible on the UI" but I don't see code that makes that, right? Please also respond with @AlexMamo